# How can I fix a left hand DIV while until the right hand div has finished scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a test web page with three sections.  The first and third sections are both full page size (100% width and height).  The center section however, is split into two halves with a title on the left and content on the right.  What I'm trying to achieve is that when you scroll to the second section, the left hand side locks into place when it's scrolled to the top of the screen and then continues to scroll once the content on the right has been passed.

I've so far attempted to achieve this with Bootstraps affix property but can't seem to get that to work no matter what I try.  This is my test markup...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Section 1 -->
    <section class="fullpage" style="background-color:#0ff;">
    </section>

    <!-- Section 2 -->
    <section class="fullpage">

        <div class="sectiontitle">
            <h1>THIS SHOULD STAY IN PLACE</h1>
            <h1>UNTIL GREEN GETS TO BOTTOM</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="sectiondetail">
            <p>Hello world this is a test</p><p>Hello world this is a test</p><p>Hello world this is a test</p>
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- Section 3 -->
    <section class="fullpage" style="background-color:#ff0;">
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS I'm using...

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
h1, h2, h3, p{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
h1{
  padding:50px 0 50px 50px;
}
p{
  padding:20px;
}

.fullpage{
  min-height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
}

.sectiontitle{
  position:absolute;
  width:50%;
  left:0px;
  background-color:#f00;
  height:100vh;
}

.sectiondetail{
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  left:50%;
  background-color:#0f0;
  height:200vh;
}
```

I'd actually prefer to use Bootstrap but is there a nice easy way to achieve this with just CSS and/or JQuery?

EDIT: Found this page which does something similar to what I'm looking for. Just scroll down beyond the first page.

[Example website with required behaviour](http://melaniedaveid.com/)

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Answer (score -1):

you can try following this is with pure css idea is to tweak with z-indexes.if you need more smooth and clean effect you can use jquery or parallax plugins

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1 {
  padding: 50px 0 50px 50px;
}
p {
  padding: 20px;
}
.fullpage {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.sectiontitle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 100vh;
}
.sectiondetail {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.magic {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="fullpage" style="background-color:#0ff;">
</section>

<!-- Section 2 -->
<section class="fullpage" style="position:relative;background:green;">

  <div class="sectiontitle">
    <h1>THIS SHOULD STAY IN PLACE</h1>
    <h1>UNTIL GREEN GETS TO BOTTOM</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="magic">
    <div class="sectiondetail">
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
      <p>Hello world this is a test</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>

<!-- Section 3 -->
<section class="fullpage" style="background-color:#ff0;">
</section>
```

Comment: Would you ever use your own suggestion in a real-life respectable website?